# Name for closure property: set of maps closed under taking $(f,g)\mapsto (f-g)/2$

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, terminology, vector-spaces

Suppose that $F$ is a collection of functions mapping some set $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, with the following closure property: whenever $f,g\in F$, we also have $(f-g)/2\in F$. Is there a name for this closure property? It is weaker than linearity.

Comment: If you also add the condition that $F$ is closed under $f \mapsto -f$ then it's equivalent to being closed under $\frac{f + g}{2}$ which is a weak form of being closed under convex linear combinations.

Comment: Right... But I wanted to avoid assuming additional conditions. In case you're curious about the motivation, see Lemma 18 here
https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.04763